# AspectJ and Kotlin in IntelliJ - does not show advised methods

Tags: java, intellij-idea, kotlin, aspectj

I have this snippet of code:

```
@Aspect
@Component
open class Advice
{
    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* project.service..*(..)) && !within(is(FinalType))", throwing = "throwable")
    open fun sendError(throwable: Exception)
    {
    println("exception thrown")
    }
}
```

It seems to be working okay, except that IJ does not tell me what methods are advised - this functionality works only when I rewrite this class to Java.
[image: q]

(this little icon on line 12 is what is missing in Kotlin - it shows the list of methods advised by the advice. It's present when the code is written in Java)

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your observation is correct. Not all features of IntelliJ IDEA automatically work for all supported languages; this one is implemented only for Java.

Comment: AspectJ support in general had a good start in older IntelliJ versions, but has been neglected for years. As much as I love IDEA, I usually switch to Eclipse + AJDT if I want to do anything aspect-related, even though AJDT has not improved much in the last few years either but it merely kept functioning. Still it is better than IDEA because AspectJ is an Eclipse project.

Comment: How did you get aspectj working with kotlin? I tried following the link - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49319700/6743176,  but no luck. Can you help?

Comment: @KashishMalhotra could you please provide more information why is it not working? any stacktrace? code?

Comment: I used aspectj with kotlin in an android application. If I convert my @Aspect annotated class in Java, the code works fine. But if I use it in kotlin, the code simply doesn't get executed, no errors, nothing.

Comment: I can't seem to find @Component annotation. Maybe that's the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue.

Workaround:

1. Create java file
2. Put your aop here
3. Debug/test/develop
4. Move the code to Kotlin file then

It's a bit ugly but is working.