# Kotlin: Possible to modify functions during compile time through metaprogramming?

Tags: kotlin, overloading, kotlin-extension, self-modifying

In dynamic languages like JavaScript/Python, it's possible to overwrite or "modify" functions during run-time. For example, in order to modify the `alert` function in JS, one could do:

```
const _prev_alert = window.alert;
window.alert = function() {
  _prev_alert.apply(this, arguments);
  console.log("Alert function was called!");
}
```

This would output "Alert function was called!" to the console every time the `alert` function is called.

Now, obviously something like this would be impossible during runtime in Kotlin-JVM or Kotlin-Native due to their static nature. However, in regards to those same languages, is it possible to perhaps modify a non-compiled function during compile time? I don't mean pre-compiled functions from libraries, but instead functions I have written in the same project I'm developing on.

For example, let's say I have a function I wrote called `get_number`. Could I modify `get_number` to return a different number without changing how its called in main and without modifying its code directly? (Or is there a way I COULD write the original `get_number` so modification IS possible down the line?)

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(get_number())
}

fun get_number(): Int {
    return 3
}

// Without modifying the code above, can I get main to print something besides 3?
```

I've been reading into Kotlin's metaprogramming with Annotations and Reflections, so perhaps those could control the compiler's behavior and overwrite `get_number`'s code? Or is this complete lunacy and the only way something of this nature would be possible is through developing my own, separate, metaprogramming wrapper over Kotlin?

*Also, just to double-clarify, this question is not about Kotlin-JS and the answer (if it exists) should be applicable to Kotlin-JVM or Native.*

Comment: It's a little bit unclear what the end goal is here. From an application design perspective, it's almost always more desirable to use an appropriate design pattern than to start relying on things like [dynamic proxies](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/proxy.html), [reflection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html) or [AOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming). So, can it be done? Yes. Should it be done? Probably not.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen It's intent is for a port of a casual, extendable, educational game development library that uses a similar metaprogramming style with JavaScript. The modifications are mostly abstracted, just to be clear, they're simply used for quick and compatible extension developments that don't tamper with the source. This isn't some bizarre question regarding how to avoid class implementation/extension or general structure, more just a curious inquiry regarding the potential of Kotlin metaprogramming. Since you claim it could be done, perhaps you could expand upon that in an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As stated in my comment: in almost all cases, it's  more desirable to use an appropriate design pattern than to start relying on things like [dynamic proxies](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/proxy.html), [reflection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html), or [AOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) to address this kind of problem.

That being said, the question asks whether it's *possible* to modify Kotlin functions at compile time through meta-programming, and the answer is *"Yes"*. To demonstrate, below is a complete example that uses [AspectJ](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/).

---

### Project structure

I set up a small [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/)-based project with the following structure:

```
.
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        └── kotlin
            ├── Aop.kt
            └── Main.kt
```

I'll reproduce the contents of all files in the sections below.

---

### Application code

The actual application code is in the file named **`Main.kt`**, and—except for the fact that I renamed your function to be in line with [Kotlin naming rules](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#naming-rules)—it's identical to the code provided in your question. The `getNumber()` method is designed to return **3**.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(getNumber())
}

fun getNumber(): Int {
    return 3
}
```

---

### AOP code

The AOP-related code is in **`Aop.kt`**, and is very simple. It has an `@Around` advice with a point cut that matches the execution of the `getNumber()` function. The advice will intercept the call to the `getNumber()` method and return **42** (instead of **3**).

```
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect

@Aspect
class Aop {
    @Around("execution(* MainKt.getNumber(..))")
    fun getRealNumber(joinPoint: ProceedingJoinPoint): Any {
        return 42
    }
}
```

(Note how the name of the generated class for the `Main.kt` file is `MainKt`.)

---

### POM file

The POM file puts everything together. I'm using 4 plugins:

- The [`kotlin-maven-plugin`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-maven.html) takes care of compiling the Kotline files. The configuration includes the execution of the [kapt](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html) plugin to process the AspectJ annotations.
- The [`jcabi-maven-plugin`](https://plugin.jcabi.com/index.html) executes the [AspectJ compiler/weaver](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/ajc-ref.html) to weave the aspects into the binary classes.
- The [`maven-jar-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/) builds the JAR file with a manifest that references the main class.
- The [`maven-shade-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) builds a [fat JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19150811/3558960) that includes all library dependencies.

This is the complete POM file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>x.y.z</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-aop</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.2.61</kotlin.version>
        <aspectj.version>1.9.1</aspectj.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>kapt</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>kapt</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jcabi</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcabi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.14.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>ajc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>MainKt</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

---

### Building and executing

To build, as with any Maven project, you just need to run:

```
mvn clean package
```

This will build a fat JAR at the `target/kotlin-aop-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` location. This JAR can then be executed using the `java` command:

```
java -jar target/kotlin-aop-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Execution then gives us the following result, demonstrating that everything worked as expected:

> 42

<sub>(Application was built and executed using the most recent Oracle Java 8 JDK at the time of writing—1.8.0_181)</sub>

---

### Conclusion

As the example above demonstrates, it's certainly possible to redefine Kotlin functions, but—to reiterate my original point—in almost all cases, there are more elegant solutions available to achieve what you need.

Comment: I wholeheartedly disagree with your assertion that "it's more desirable to use an appropriate design pattern than to start relying on things like dynamic proxies, reflection, or AOP".  In fact, I maintain that it's precisely those things that comprise an elegant solution.  Please enlighten me as to other, "more elegant solutions" to the problems that AOP solves.  For example, how would you implement something like domain-object security without an AOP-based solution?  An example of your solution would go a long way to change my opinion.

Comment: Also, there is one clarification that I'd make regarding your example project given above.  You have demonstrated that it's possible to _weave_ binary .class files _after_ they've been compiled by the Kotlin compiler & kapt.  That is distinct from, say, using ajc to compile the whole lot in one go, like you can in Java.  My interpretation of the OP's question refers to the latter, not the former.  Perhaps the OP's question should have been something like "How do I compile my Kotlin files with an AOP compiler like ajc so that compilation & weaving is completed in a single step?" or similar.