# Is there a way to make AspectJ weaving work, now that AGP removed Transform API?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, aspectj

I've been using the Transform API in my Android app to do some AspectJ weaving. Transform API worked well especially because it [guaranteed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64673644) that both Kotlin and Java classes would be available for transformation. However, Android Gradle Plugin 8 removed that API in favor of [some replacements](https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin-api-updates#replacement_apis).

I looked around and there's just not much information on these. So it would be great if someone had a ready recipe for marrying AspectJ and one of these APIs.

Comment: Unclear if you've read: https://jdvp.me/articles/Switching-AspectJ-Plugins-Android and https://jdvp.me/articles/AOP-in-Android-2023 which expresses the author's thoughts.